# WooCommerce - If shipping class hide field

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I wish to hide a specific checkout field based on shipping class. So if the cart contains a product with that shipping class an input fields should be hidden.

Anyone who can help me archive this?

Thanks

Comment: It is a regular field like the address 2. If I can just add a class to the field or inject some css to hide it, it will be fine

Answer (score 0):

By "specific checkout field" do you mean shipping method. Because there is a free plugin which can [Hide WooCommerce Shipping Method Based on Shipping Class and Shipping Zone](https://www.pluginhive.com/hide-woocommerce-shipping-methods-based-on-shipping-class-and-zone/).

If you want to hide the shipping method please let me know I will show how you can do it with the help of the above plugin.

Comment: No, it just a regular text field - billing address 2 - which in this case i used for another purphose :)